# Functions Execution

Tags: python

There are three scenarios when a main function waits for its call-backs to finish.
I've made an attempt to get one that "fools" main to proceed. There are times I have to insert

> time.sleep(0.1)

to avoid it from happening. While it makes a trick it would be interesting for find a solution.
A question: how to prevent a situation when a function that calls doesn't wait till a function called.

```
import time
import urllib2

class MyClass():
    def calcA(arg=None):
        print "\tstartA"
        for i in range(25000000):i+=1
        print '\t\tcompletedA'
    def calcB(arg=None):
        print "\tstartB"
        time.sleep(3)
        print '\t\tcompletedB'
    def calcC(arg=None):
        print "\tstartC"
        response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.example.com/')
        html = response.read()
        print '\t\tcompletedC'

def runTestA():
    myInst=MyClass()
    print 'call1...'
    myInst.calcA()
    print 'call2...'
    myInst.calcB()
    print 'call3...'
    myInst.calcC()

runTestA()
print "happy end"
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Those aren't callbacks, they're stand method calls. Unless you're using threading or processes, Python will always wait for a method to return a result before continuing.

Comment: Are you expecting these functions to run in parallel?  They won't, these aren't callbacks they are function calls, and they are synchronous.  So `calcA()` will complete before `calcB()` starts.

Comment: I wish! I have an impression it is not always so... I would be happy to know it never happens.

Comment: is b a callback?: def a(arg=None):pass; b=a; c=a(b)

Comment: @Sputnix No. A callback is a function passed to another function or object and supposed to be called by that when it is due. Thus the "back".

Comment: Do not want to be rude, but your impression is not supported by facts. :D Try to run this code million times and show us log in which you will prove your point.

Otherwise believe us, python executes functions in sequence. :)

Comment: Also callback does not imply that code is asynchronous or will be executed asynchronous. Please refer to: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python always execute functions in sequence unless you use threading, processes or libraries like stackless python or celery (however usually those libraries are just extensions on top of processes and/or threads).